# Adding multiple headers to graphql client (apollo-boost)

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-boost

```
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri,
    onError: (e: any) => {
      console.log('error: ', e); // Failed to fetch
      console.log(e.operation.getContext()); // it does show it has x-abc-id
    },

    request: operation => {
      const headers: { [x: string]: string } = {};
      const accessToken = AuthService.getUser()?.accessToken;
      const activeClientId = UserService.getActiveClientId();
      headers['x-abc-id'] = activeClientId;
      if (accessToken) headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
      operation.setContext({ headers });
    }
```

});

The problem here is when i just add **Authorization** header it makes the POST call and shows the expected error.

But when i add **x-abc-id** header which is also expected by backend it only makes OPTIONS call (no post call)

P.S. On postman adding both headers works completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found what the issue was, thought to share if it help.

Postman does not perform [OPTIONS call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x44BK.png) before sending request to backend.

In OPTIONS call, represents **what client call contains: [authorization, content-type, x-abc-id]**
[image]

**BUT** what does server expects: 
[image]

Just **authorization, content-type**
So it's a calls headers mismatch (nothing related to Apollo).

**x-abc-id header** explicitly has to be allowed in CORS configuration on backend.

Thanks to [Pooria Atarzadeh](https://dev.to/p0oker/why-is-my-browser-sending-an-options-http-request-instead-of-post-5621)